# Add object to list in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to add object `first` to `myMovie`to localstorage. But myMovie is always empty when check localstorage.

```
var myMovie= [];
    localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
    var output = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myMovie'));
    var first= {id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"}
        myMovie.push(first);
```

I can't figure out what I'm I doing it wrong here.

Comment: `myMovie` contains a String, a representation of the current state of the Array. It's like taking a Picture and wondering why the picture doesn't change. Because you have moved, but the picture doesn't. You have to `setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie))` every time you want to update the state in the `localStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best would be a function, that not only changes the array but also stores it in localStorage:

```js
    var myMovie=[] //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myMovie')||"[]");
    
    function push(el){
    myMovie.push(el);
    //localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
    }

    function remove(title){
     var i=myMovie.findIndex(movie=>movie.title===title);
     if(i!==-1){
       myMovie.splice(i,1);
       //localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
     }
    }
    
    push({id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016", type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"});
    console.log(myMovie);
    remove("La La Land");
    console.log(myMovie);
```

To make a running stackSnippet, i had to remove the localStorage functionality, it is commented out.

Comment: Post this as answer on second post, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it looks like you are writing your object in the storage **before** actually adding the first item to it.

Try to add the content in the list at first or save it again after each updates.

```
var myMovie= [];
var first= {id:"tt3783958", title:"La La Land", year:"2016",
            type:"Comedy, Drama, Music"};
myMovie.push(first);

localStorage.setItem('myMovie', JSON.stringify(myMovie));
var output = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myMovie'));
```

Comment: This actually works! Is there any way to remove 'first' object from 'myMovie'?

Comment: Yes, store in a local storage it's like a save, not a bind of a storage.

Comment: @Slasher Do modification in your myMovie object, and resave your object in the storage.